# How would one go about determining the time since a window has been opened in React/JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, timeout

**TL;DR**: My page crashes because slow API call doesn't give necessary data to a function that loads a table. Current workaround is setting delay on buttonclick table open, but unnecessary if the page has been open for a couple of seconds.

So I've implemented an MUI datagrid component in my project that works great, except for one catch.

The API call to retrieve the rows for the table takes a while, and as such the getRowId functional prop of the datagrid doesn't have a list fed into it initially to generate unique rowIds (necessary for an MUI datagrid to render properly I guess), therefore if a user opens the table (it's in a modal) too soon after loading the page, the page crashes.

My current workaround is that when the user clicks the button to open the modal, I setTimeout(openModal(), 2000). This works fine, but isn't necessary if the user has had the page open for a second or two. There would be no real reason for the user to open the modal right away, but I just don't want the page to crash in the case that someone does.

**The question**: Is there a way to track how long the page has been open for? So that I could, say, only setTimeout if the page has been open for less than x time?

One idea I had was to set it so that the button to open the modal is disabled on mount (useEffect() in this case) for X amount of time, and then enabled, but that seems kind of ugly.

Does anyone have a better idea? Or a completely different way to do this?

I can post code if necessary, let me know.

Thank you :)

Comment: I wouldn't base this on time, really. I think what you really want to do, is to set some state when the request for data is finished, and enable the button to open the modal at that point in time.

Comment: I think you're right. I'm realizing now that I'm already using a "loading" prop for UI purposes. Might as well use it for the button too. Thanks mate